# Left Outer Join with Nullable column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to make a query of LINQ with left outer join but with nullable column

`YarnRequsitionDetailID`  is also null in other `Yarn_PurchaseOrder_Details`  table and, I have to must apply to join on the base of it

```
  var yarnPOFilter_Grid = (from yrq in _context.Yarn_Requisition_Details
                                     join ypo in 
     _context.Yarn_PurchaseOrder_Details on yrq.YarnRequsitionDetailID equals 
      ypo.YarnRequsitionDetailID into t

     from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()  
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         YarnRequsitionDetailID = 
                                         rt.YarnRequsitionDetailID,
                                         yrq.YarnID,
                                         yrq.Yarn.YarnName,
                                         yrq.YarnFellowID,
                                         yrq.Yarn_FellowCodes.YarnFellowCode,
                                         yrq.QuantityRequired,
                                         rt.QuantityOrdered,
                                         QuantityBalance_Custom = 
      yrq.QuantityRequired - rt.QuantityOrdered
                                     }).ToList();
            return yarnPOFilter_Grid;
```

It give the following error

**The cast to value type 'System.Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.**

Comment: See msdn samples for left outer join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I already did this but not helpful in my case

Comment: The change definition from Double to Double?

Answer (score 1):

Make your `YarnRequsitionDetailID` nullable if it is nullable so you can assign null to its property

because `double` cannot accept null but `double?` can accept null

Comment: YarnRequisitionID is primary key in Yarn_Requisition_Details and foreign key in Yarn_PurchaseOrder_Details and nullable also

Answer (score 0):

Any one of the fields in the joined entity which is of a non-nullable value type should be cast in the projection expression to the corresponding nullable type. For example, if `QuantityRequired` is a required field in the database:

```
var yarnPOFilter_Grid = (
        ...
        from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty() select new {
            ...
            QuantityRequired = (double?)yrq.QuantityRequired,
```